# OpenCV image processing- filter an image

Tags: image-processing, opencv, filter

I would like to filter an image to make it more clear/sharper. What would be the best filter method for this in OpenCV?

Comment: First, ignore openCV.  What do you mean by "clear"?  Is the image: Blurry? Noisy? Too dark? Too light?  (Sorry, I can't help you with openCV, but I can help you with your question clarity.)

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396140/sharpening-video-images-using-opencv) shares code that performs what you are looking for, and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4993701/176769) as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to sharpen the image [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993082/how-to-sharpen-an-image-in-opencv) question might help you.

And for noise reduction [here](http://www.aishack.in/2010/01/noise-reduction-by-averaging/) I have found an interesting article.

Answer (score 1):

Filtering is a very broad topic and "make it more clear" is a rather vague objective. OpenCV has a number of filters implemented for you to try, and they are [documented fairly extensively](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#image-filtering). If you are wanting more detailed advice, perhaps you should show some example images and explain what specifically you want to improve about them.